# I want to make a clear button for my calculator so when I type C at any time it will restart from the calculator image

Tags: java

Starting from the calculator image and below, I want it to clear the calculator and to restart the calculator from the image. How do I do that?
Basically the calculator can do simple addition, multiplication, division, and subtraction, and square roots and some exponents.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
public class Calculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String message = "Hello, this calculator can solve any addition, 
division, \n\nmutliplication, and subtraction problem. And can solve a few 
equations \n\nPlease type the problem you want to solve then press 
enter\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    slowPrint(message, 30);



    System.out.println("|━━━━━━━━━━|");
    System.out.println("|                 |");
    System.out.println("|━━━━━━━━━━|");
    System.out.println("|[CE] [C] [+] [-] | ");
    System.out.println("|[1] [2] [3] [^]  |");
    System.out.println("|[4] [5] [6] [/]  |");
    System.out.println("|[7] [8] [9] [*]  |");
    System.out.println("|[0] [.] [=] [√]  |");
    System.out.println("|                 |");
    System.out.println("|━━━━━━━━━━|\n\n");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please type the operation you would like to use exactly how it looks like on the calculator. \n\n(for sqrt the second number you put is what is being rooted and type sqrt)");

    String opchoice = userInput.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please type the first number you would like to use.\n\n");
    String a;
    //converts a string to an integer
    a = scan.nextLine();
    String number = a;
    double result = Double.parseDouble(number);


    System.out.println("Please type the second number you would like to use.\n\n");
    String b;
    b = scan.nextLine();
    String secondnumber = b;
    double secondresult = Double.parseDouble(secondnumber);


    double addsolution;
    double subsolution;
    double mulsolution;
    double divsolution;
    double sqrtsolution;
    double expsolution;
    switch (opchoice){

    case "+" :
    addsolution = result + secondresult;
    System.out.println(""+result+" plus "+secondresult+" equals "+addsolution+" ");
    break;

    case "-" :
    subsolution = result - secondresult;
    System.out.println(" "+result+" minus "+secondresult+" equals "+subsolution+" ");
    break;

    case "*" :
    mulsolution = result * secondresult;
    System.out.println(" "+result+" times "+secondresult+" equals "+mulsolution+" ");
    break;

    case "/" :
    divsolution = result / secondresult;
    System.out.println(" "+result+" divided by "+secondresult+" equals "+divsolution+" ");
    break;

    case "sqrt" :
    sqrtsolution = Math.sqrt(secondresult);
    System.out.println(" The square root of "+secondresult+" is  "+sqrtsolution+" ");
    break;

    case "^" :

    expsolution = Math.pow(result, secondresult);
    System.out.println(" "+result+" to the power of "+secondresult+" equals "+expsolution+" ");
    break;









}


}

/**
 * Function to print each character in a string with a delay (a "typewriter" effect)
 * @param message The string to print
 * @param millisPerChar Milliseconds to take to print each character
 */
public static void slowPrint(String message, long millisPerChar)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print(message.charAt(i));

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(millisPerChar);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: put the calculator image printing in a separate method, call the method when "C" is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
String[] img = new String[]{
        "|━━━━━━━━━━|",
        "|                 |",
        "|━━━━━━━━━━|",
        "|[CE] [C] [+] [-] | ",
        "|[1] [2] [3] [^]  |",
        "|[4] [5] [6] [/]  |",
        "|[7] [8] [9] [*]  |",
        "|[0] [.] [=] [√]  |",
        "|                 |",
        "|━━━━━━━━━━|\n\n"
    };

    //all you need to do is use these three lines of code when you want to 
 //reshow it
 for (int i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(img[i]);
}
```

You store the string image in a string array and then print out the different lines when you need them. You could also store it in one string with the \n between lines. The main part is storing it so it can be reused.